# HIgh CPU usage - Will using cache plugins help

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, memory

i am having issues with CPU high utilization,  more than 92% .

Is there anyway to track which plugin or process or user is causing this issue?

Will usage of any cache plugin will help this or not ?

Comment: this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) should do the trick. (Helping you to find which plugin uses too much resources (possible reason for too high cpu/mem use)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to see what is causing it is to disable all plugins and add them back one at a time. If that doesn't reveal it, switch to a default theme. After that I'd say it is something server side.

To answer your question though - caching should help but it depends on what is causing the high usage.